# Is there a way to change the input data type?

Tags: python

I'm coding in python and I want to find out whether there's a way to change the data type of an input. I've devised a code to represent my question:

```
        menu= input("test>>> ")
    if (menu)==("forprint"):
    fortimes= input ("range>>>>")
    forprintwhat= input ("print>>>>>")
    for x in range (fortimes):
        print (forprintwhat)
```

Now obviously, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/vas71/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/leaf.py", line 15, in <module>
for x in range (fortimes):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Note: the error message says 'line 15' because I'm copying it from a larger body of text.
My question is, how do I make the string an integer so that my code works? Is it possible?
Thank you for the help!

Comment: you can use the function `int` to convert a string to a integer https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int

Comment: Please try `int(fortimes)` in the for loop.

Comment: right... but how do I use it in the code?(I'm still a beginner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast your input to integer:

```
fortimes = int(input("range>>>>"))
```

Please allow me to suggest you to have input validation by using try-except block. Something simple like:

```
while True:
    try:
        fortimes = int(input("range>>>>"))
        break
    except:
        print("Enter valid range (numeric)")
```

In case a user enters invalid range input.